# strtotime and DateTime::createFromFormat return wrong date

Tags: php, laravel-5, php-7

`strtotime()` and  `DateTime::createFromFormat` return wrong date

and

```
 date('m/d/y H:i A', strtotime('09/29/2018 4:15 PM'))
```

return me `09/29/18 16:15 PM`

Why is that, and how to fix it?

Comment: You're using `m` to mean both month and minutes - the latter needs `i`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `i` instead of `m` for month.
In addition, you need to use `h` instead of `H`, to show the hours in the 12 hours format.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/y h:i A', '09/30/18 10:00 AM');
echo  $date->format('m/d/y h:i');
```

As you can see, m is already used for the month, so if you would have looked to the php.net documentation, you would have found that there are different letters for the hours.

Comment: date('m/d/y H:i A', strtotime('09/29/2018 4:15 PM')) 


return me `09/29/18 16:15 PM`

Why is that?

Comment: You need to use h instead of H, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use i for minute

```
  $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/y H:i A', '09/30/18 10:00 AM');
```